# Popup window Mac OS in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cocoa, popup

Can I make on Qt is popup window?

[image: click for example]

I do not know exactly how it is called.

Comment: Yes... QSystemTrayIcon... Example here https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-systemtrayexample.html and many more can be found on google.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`QSystemTrayIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html). That creates a tray icon in the taskbar, which is where the notification will come from. To show the notification, use the `showMessage` method. This method takes two `QString` parameters, the first one being the title and the second one being the message. For example, the following code shows a "Hello World!" message with "Title" as title:

```
QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(button);
trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon("image.png"));
trayIcon->show();
trayIcon->showMessage("Title", "Hello World!");
```

You must set the tray icon's icon by using the `setIcon` method, otherwise it won't work. You also have to show the tray icon with the `show` method. You can also do something when the message is clicked on with the `messageClicked` signal.

Here is a complete example of a program where clicking on a button will show the message, and clicking on the message will show a normal message box:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton button("Show message");
    QSystemTrayIcon trayIcon;

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&trayIcon](){
        trayIcon.showMessage("Title", "Hello World!");    //Show the popup when the button is clicked on
    });

    QObject::connect(&trayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::messageClicked, [](){
        QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "", "Message Clicked");    //Show a message box when the popup is clicked on
    });

    trayIcon.setIcon(QIcon("image.png"));    //Set the tray icon icon to image.png

    trayIcon.show();    //Show the tray icon
    button.show();    //Show the button

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the result on Windows:

[image]

And here is the result on Mac:

[image]

I've circled the tray icon on both screenshots so that you can see what a tray icon looks like. Try clicking on the popups to see what happens. You can play around with the code to change the messages and the image to really understand how the code works.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wanted. He's not asking how to show a message from a tray icon. Rather how to pop-up a dialog from an tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QMenu`, `QAction`s and the `TrayIcon` to do this.

```cpp
void Window::createTrayIcon(){
    TrayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
    TrayIconMenu->addAction(MinimizeAction);
    TrayIconMenu->addAction(MaximizeAction);
    TrayIconMenu->addAction(RestoreAction);
    TrayIconMenu->addSeparator();
    TrayIconMenu->addAction(QuitAction);

    TrayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    TrayIcon->setContextMenu(TrayIconMenu);
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the exact format of that rounded bubble though. That might not be a feature Qt has.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when answering a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)